# Spring Security OAuth2 with multiple IDPs and form login: matching users

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I've used Spring Security multiple times on several projects, including 3 legged OAuth2 authentication on Zuul API Gateway, etc. All works brilliant and official documentation is very neat and simple.

But there is one point that I still don't get from docs. Imagine you have a spring based [Resource Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-boot-property-mappings) with [several ID Providers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2login-boot-property-mappings), and also you have your own user database and form login.

Thus, users can be authenticated either via form login or via one of IDPs (let's say Google or Facebook).

The question is: how to match Authentication from any of your IDPs to Authentication object that is enhanced by/mapped to your local user?

I.e.: Alice has an account in your system (in your database). She goes into her "profile" and declares that she also has a Google or Facebook account. OK, done, you save this info somewhere in your system.

Now, when Alice login into your system via social network, what spring API do you use to understand that Alice entered via Google is exact same Alice that is already registered in your DB? In what API do you enhance her Authentication with authorities based on your DB?

Thanks in advance, guys

Comment: Have you considered using your own OAuth2 server that would accept third parties (Google, Facebook ...) and support creating it's own users? Then your application would deal only with tokens issued by your auth provider.

Comment: Exactly) This is how it works on one of our projects. But here we have another requirements(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this is typically done is by creating a composite that contains both the `OidcUser` object and your domain object. For example:

```
@Component
public class MyOAuth2UserService implements OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> {
    private final OidcUserService delegate = new OidcUserService();

    @Override
    public OidcUser loadUser(OidcUserRequest oidcUserRequest) {
        // the information that comes back from google, et al
        OidcUser oidcUser = this.delegate.loadUser(oidcUserRequest);

        // the information from your DB
        MyUser user = this.myRepository.findUserByXYZ(oidcUser.getXYZ());

        return new MyOidcUser(user, oidcUser);
    }

    private static class MyOidcUser extends MyUser implements OidcUser {
        private final OidcUser delegate;

        public MyOidcUser(MyUser user, OidcUser oidcUser) {
            super(user);
            this.delegate = oidcUser;
        }

        // ... implement delegate methods
    }
}
```

Note that `XYZ` is some attribute that allows you to know that the user from Google is the user from your system. Maybe that's the email address, for example.

The benefit to this extra bit of work is that Spring Security will place this `MyOidcUser` object into `Authentcation#getPrincipal`. So now, if you need to get your domain bits, you do `(MyUser) authentication.getPrincipal()`, but if you need the OIDC bits, you do `(OidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal()`. Depending on your use cases, you may be able to do something as simple as:

```
@GetMapping("/endpoint1")
public String endpoint1(@AuthenticationPrincipal MyUser myUser) {
    // ...
}

@GetMapping("/endpoint2")
public String endpoint2(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser) {
    URL issuer = oidcUser.getIdToken().getIssuer();
    // ...
}
```